# How to open files from other machine running ubuntu

Tags: networking, share

I tried to take data from my pc to laptop. Both are using ubuntu 11.10 os. I googled and tried to connect both the systems. Now it is showing connected symbol. Dont know how to proceed further. I need to take data from my pc using this lan connection. Please provide me solution for this...

Comment: Open file manager , at the left you will find Network menu , try Browse Network .

Comment: Have you tried **File >> Connect to Server** (and choose SSH), from either of the PCs to the other?  This will provide a GUI method to drag-and-drop files between the two. Do you want a shared directory?  What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 4):

You can always try this:

1. On the folder you want to share, right click :

[image: Right Click]

2. Check the Share this button

[image]

3. Say yes to install additional software
4. Finally, click on Create Share to share the folder; the folder’s icon will look like the following:

[image]

Now everything is done. To access the shared folder through other computers of the network, just open up Nautilus, in the left sidebar click on Browse Network then choose the name of the computer in which the folder is shared and you will see it.

[image]

[Source](http://followthegeeks.com/how-to-share-folders-in-lan-ubuntu/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba?action=show&redirect=SettingUpSamba) on setting up Samba for file sharing.

It is possible that things will work by default , out of the box, as long as you have user accounts setup properly on both Ubuntu machines.  Otherwise, you need to read the guide and figure it out yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You can share folders through Ubuntu, or use a cloud solution like Dropbox. If you use Dropbox, all you need is an internet connection

1. Install Dropbox on your pc for example
2. Upload your files to your Dropbox folder,
3. Install Dropbox on your laptop
4. Retrieve your files in your Dropbox folder

A similar solution and a native one for Ubuntu is Ubuntu One, it's the same principle that Dropbox, but it's already installed on your Ubuntu. If you want to know how to do the same thing but using Ubuntu One there's an excellent guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/internet/C/networking-shares.html)

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage of using an intermediate server over the internet, which can be slow, or even impossible, depending on the volume of the shared data.

Comment: While this solution is a cute answer its not really a "Linux" solution to the problem.  I don't think it would qualify as a solid answer.

Comment: In deed if it's a lot of data, it can be slow. I use Dropbox with something like 4GB and it works pretty well, and i don't even have a great internet connection. It wasn't specified the amount of data to transfer.

Comment: @MariosZindilis if both of the computers are in the same LAN that is not true since [dropbox supports LAN synchronisation](https://www.dropbox.com/help/137/en)

Comment: LAN Sync in Dropbox only prevents downloading of changed files from Dropbox servers, Upload still needs to go to the cloud once. Dropbox therefore binds your solution to an internet connection and creates a bottleneck the size of your bandwidth.